# CP - Difference between --no-dereference (-P) and -d options

Tags: symlink, cp

What is the difference between `--no-dereference` (`-P`) and `-d` options for the *cp* command?

I know `-d` is the same as if both `--no-dereference` and `--preserve=links` were specified but what exactly does `--preserve=links` do? Should I use `-d` or `-P`?

Comment: There is no `-d` option in the `cp` command.

Comment: @schily [Yes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) there is: https://i.imgur.com/DMJFk41.png

Comment: No, you are not quoting the `cp` documentation but a vendor specific command called `gcp`. The real `cp` documentation is here. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I guess I'm referring to the [GNU `cp` **command**](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html) and not the `cp` of the IEEE **specification** ?? Well, to be honest, I didn't know I had to check the IEEE standards specifications and specify that the option I'm referring to is not in the command's specification.